# array.array() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, typeerror, k-means

Trying to do a k means clustering on FARS dataset, getting the array.array() takes no keyword arguments error and don't understand why or how to correct it.

Initially was getting errors for int32 which I changed to np.int32 and that corrected but now I am getting the array error and can't figure out how to fix it.

Full error:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-11-29801179ab6c> in <cell line: 5>()
          3 kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X)
          4 kmeans.labels_
    ----> 5 array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=np.int32)
          6 kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
          7 array([1, 0], dtype=np.int32)

TypeError: array.array() takes no keyword arguments
```

Code:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
...               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=np.int32)
kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
array([1, 0], dtype=np.int32)
kmeans.cluster_centers_
array([[10.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

Comment: What do you mean? What is the error?

Comment: The error just shows as TypeError: array.array() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Show the full traceback

Comment: When does this error occur? Provide the output of the exception.

Comment: Full error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-29801179ab6c> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X)
      4 kmeans.labels_
----> 5 array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=np.int32)
      6 kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
      7 array([1, 0], dtype=np.int32)

TypeError: array.array() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: It is unclear what array is, its not the same as np.array, you defined a function called  array?

Comment: Show the relevant import statement(s) that imports `array` and NumPy (or even just all import statements for clarity).

Comment: Did you perchance do `from numpy import array`? Are your sure that `array` is in fact a numpy array? It would help us to see the declaration of `array` here

Comment: Since this is a Jupyter notebook, you might have set a variable `array = np.array(...)` earlier, then went back to a top cell and rerun that code. But now, `array` is different than it was before. Try restarting the kernel and then rerunning your cells (top-down).

Comment: @JRiggles. I think each line like `array(...)` is simply the output of the previous statement. Check my answer, I get the same output.

Comment: I followed the advice here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

But the array command wasn't working so I found advice that said add
from array import array

which I did

Comment: @LouisaWareing. It's exactly what I wrote. All relevant lines start with `>>>` (The python interpreter prompt). The rest is the result of statements. This is a convention :)

Comment: @Corralien Ah, that makes sense! Fair point.

Comment: Thank you all for the help here, I'm new to Python so finding it all a bit confusing but this has been a huge help - thank you!

Comment: Ah, sounds like too much copy-paste of example code (and its output) then.

Comment: As an aside: " I found advice that said add from array import array ": that is a completely different array, which has nothing to do with NumPy or Scikit-learn; in those contexts, you'll want to avoid this  array type (just don't import it) and use the NumPy one instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't copy/paste your code as it, some lines are the output of the previous line. This lines are not intended to be used as statements:

```
>>> kmeans.labels_
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=np.int32)  # this is the output of kmeans.labels_

>>> kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
array([1, 0], dtype=np.int32)  # this is the output of kmeans.predict(...)

>>> kmeans.cluster_centers_
array([[10.,  2.],  # this is the output of kmean.cluster_centers_
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

The code should be:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X)
labels = kmeans.labels_
preds = kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

Usage:

```
>>> labels
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)

>>> preds
array([1, 0], dtype=int32)

>>> centroids
array([[10.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#loading-an-example-dataset) said:

> Our notational convention is that `$` denotes the shell prompt while `>>>` denotes the Python interpreter prompt: